# R convert pdf to binary image

Tags: r, pdf, image-processing

I have a pdf with mostly text and borders, but the encoding is corrupted, so I basically need to render it as a binary image so I can perform  edge detection to segment it and ocr to parse the file.

Right now I'm using `pdftools` to render it as a color image and then `magick` to convert it to a bilevel image, but it takes far too much time.

Is there a faster/more direct way to do this in R?

Comment: Since `magick` is already using libraries (not R code) to do its work, I think it's unlikely that an R solution could do any better. You might do well if you post your code here and/or translate to `magick.exe` (cli) code and ask over at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or one of the other sites.

Comment: @r2evans or perhaps even Inkspace. If I remember correctly, it has a CLI.

Comment: maybe "batch conversion" (bimp) using gimp?

Comment: maybe `pdftools` in combination with `tesseract` ocr.